# Excel Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am new to Visual Basic. I created a spreadsheet which worked fine until I copied entries from it to another sheet!

Apparently, whenever I click the CONTINUE button on the Find Entry form I get the runtime error 1004 also the drop down shows nothing in it yet I never changed the code. When I click Debug,

```
TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnD_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Full_Name"), 0)
```

is highlighted and I don’t know how to proceed with it as I never touched this line of code at all.

What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Below is my code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim TargetRow As Integer

    TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnD_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Full_Name"), 0)
    Sheets("Engine").Range("B5").Value = TargetRow

    Unload Find_Entry_UF

    Data_UF.Txt_FirstName = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value
    Data_UF.Txt_Surname = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value


    Data_UF.Combo_Age = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value
    Data_UF.Combo_Marital = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value
    Data_UF.Combo_Gender = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value


    If Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value = "Yes" Then
        Data_UF.Option_Y_Children = True
    Else
        Data_UF.Option_N_Children = True
    End If

    Data_UF.Combo_Religion = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 8).Value
    Data_UF.Txt_Address = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 9).Value
    Data_UF.Combo_FileNumber = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 10).Value
```

Comment: You copied entries to another sheet, but you still search inside `Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Full_Name")`?

Comment: I maintained the same sheet and discarded the one I copied to

Comment: Check this named range and see where it refers to Dyn_Full_Name

Comment: @Sixthsense. I never edited this code before I copied entries

Comment: Write this before the line with the error and share the result:     `MsgBox Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Full_Name").Address`

Comment: Named range is worksheet/workbook specific.  I have not said you edited the code.  What you seen in the code is the name of the named range.  But actual reference of the named range may differ.  Press Ctrl+F3 and check the named range reference.

Comment: Also, consider that error 1004 raises with match if it finds nothing...

Comment: @Vityata , same error occurs again

Comment: @codemia - that's great! This means that you do not have `Dyn_Full_Name` on a sheet named `"Data"`.

Comment: @Sixthsense  here's the Reference for the Entry Form   =OFFSET(Data!#REF!,0,0,Engine!$B$3,1)

Comment: Data!#REF this means that the reference is getting deleted and thats why you see #Reference in that named range.  So refer your previous file and get the address of that named range and incorporate it in your current file.

Comment: @Sixthsense. I have two forms on this sheet. The other one is   Data_Start and references to  =Data!$A$4

Answer (score 0):

The 1004 error comes from the fact, that in the Excel file at least 1 of the following 2 conditions are missing:

- There is no sheet named `Data`
- There is no named range `Dyn_Full_Name` on the sheet `Data`

Adjust the worksheet correspondingly and error would be fixed.

Comment: both of these are available

Comment: @codemia - what happens if you write `MsgBox ColumnD_Menu` before the error?

Comment: When I Write MsgBox ColumnD_Menu before the error line of code and test. A Microsoft Excel Message box pops up

Comment: @codemia - this means that `ColumnD_Menu` is not correctly assigned. Write `Dim columnD_Menu as Long : columnD_Menu = 4` to assign it.

Comment: I have tried it but the error comes back again. When I click Debug , This line of code is highlighted     TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnD_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range("Dyn_Full_Name"), 0)

Comment: @codemia - assign some value to `columnD_Menu` and it would work.